# How to edit values of a char* string in C?

Tags: c, pointers, char, edit

I just started learning C and I'm quite unsure of how to "correctly" access and edit values of a character pointer.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  char* text = malloc(20);
  char* othertext = "Teststring";

  do
  {
    *text++ = *othertext++;
  } while (*othertext != '\0');

  printf("%s\n", text + 3);
  free(text);
  return 0;
}
```

Firstly, why does the do-while function not work? The content of "othertext" doesn't get copied to the "text" pointer. Furthermore, the program crashes when free(text) is being executed!

We know that this code works if we add a second pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char* text = malloc(20);
  char* othertext = "Teststring";

  char *ptr1 = text;
  char *ptr2 = othertext;

  do
  {
    *ptr1++ = *ptr2++;
  } while (*ptr2 != '\0');

  printf("%s\n", text + 3);
  free(text);
  return 0;
}
```

But both pointers have basically the same address! They have the same values in the debugger, so how does a second pointer make any difference?

As a final note: We are not allowed to use string.h. And we do know there's a subtle difference between arrays and pointers. But we need to specifically understand how char* works!

Comment: A `char *` is neither a string, nor an array., It is a pointer to `char`. C does not have a string type. It is all convention.

Comment: Why "correctly" in Dr Evil quotes? Do you have some weird interpretation of "correct" that differs from the common one?

Comment: Because apparently we have a "wrong" conception of how it should be copied ;)

Comment: You better had put the "we" in quotes. It definitively does not include **me**.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I and my colleague!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass to `free()` the pointer returned by `malloc()` (*the same address*). You are passing the incremented pointer i.e. the `text` pointer now doesn't have the address of the pointer returned by `malloc()` instead it's an the address of the last element of `text`, use another pointer to copy the data, or better an index

```
size_t i;
for (i = 0 ; othertext[i] != '\0' ; ++i)
    text[i] = othertext[i];
text[i] = '\0';
```

You say

> But both pointers have basically the same address!

This is not true, try this

```
printf("%p -- %p\n", (void *) text, (void *) ptr1);
```

Comment: Thank you! Okay, but one question: before the while loop, the pointers "text" and "ptr1" do have the same address. Only after the loop, they point at different addresses? So how is it really different?

Comment: Because when you do pointer arithmetic you change the address stored in the pointer, that's the point. After `ptr1++` `ptr1` points to the second character in `text`.

Comment: It's getting clearer and clearer! One last question though: if I have a "char* test;" (so it is not initialized with malloc) I cannot change the contents afterwards? Because even with a second pointer that points to "test" the program ends in a segmentation fault! Is it because we are allowed to modify in the heap? And otherwise it's read-only?

Comment: `char *test;` does not point to valid memory, you can't try to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You modify the value of the `text` pointer in your loop, such that at the end it's not pointing to the beginning of the memory region you allocated; that's (part of) why you don't see the text, and why the `free` crashes.

You need to preserve that original pointer value (which you do in your second snippet).

Answer (score 0):

You are actually changing the address that `text` is pointing too.

Consider a very simple memory in which `text` points to address `5` and `othertext` points to address `42` on which the `T` of  `TestString` has been placed.

You now copy the character found at address `42` to address `5`, so that address `5` also contains a `T`. However, you now increment the address that `text` is pointing too. In other words, `text` now points at address `6`. You also increment `othertext` which now points to address `43`.

In the next round you copy the `e` found at address `43` to address `6` and increment both again. This is all fine.

However after you are done copying `text` will point to `5 + 10 = 15`. On address `15` however you can not print anything, nor can you remove what is there.

In your second piece of code there are no problems because `text` keeps pointing to address `5`.

Answer (score 0):

do this printf inside the loop after the assignment line. I think you will see why it's not working  ;)

```
printf("%s\n", text);
```